# python classes and variable scope

Tags: python, parameters, pass-by-reference

```
class Test:

    def c(self, args):
        print args

    def b(self, args):
        args.append('d')

    def a(self):
        args = ['a', 'b', 'c']
        self.b(args)
        self.c(args)

Test().a()
```

Why doesn't this print ['a', 'b', 'c']?

Comment: BTW, this has nothing to do with Python classes or variable scope.  It's pass-by-value vs. pass-by-reference.  Python uses the latter for objects.

Comment: I wish I could accept both as answers. I appreciate the link that mizo provided but I'm marking Wern as the answer for two reasons: a) He posted first b) He has only been a member for 11 days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a list to a function, you're really passing it a pointer to the list and not a copy of the list. So `b` is appending a value to the original `args`, not its own local copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you pass to methods `b` and `c` is a reference to the list `args`, not a copy of it. In method `b`, you append to the same list you created in method `a`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference/986145#986145) for a more detailed explanation on parameter passing in Python.